# Stored procedure order of execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, function, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetLogs]
(
    @StartDate  DATETIME,
    @EndDate    DATETIME
)
AS
SELECT
    sl.ID,
    LOG10(sl.Value)
FROM
    dbo.SampleList sl
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            ID,
            RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Codec ORDER BY TimeStampUTC DESC, d.ID DESC) ranked
        FROM
            dbo.SampleList 
        WHERE
            ListDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    ) r
ON
    r.ID        =   sl.ID   AND
    r.ranked    =   1
```

I tried this stored procedure with this @StartDate = 2014-01-29 @EndDate = 2015-03-14.

And gets this error

> An invalid floating point operation occurred

The reason of the error "An Invalid floating point operation occured" is the invalid usage of mathematical function.

```
SELECT LOG10(-3);
SELECT LOG10(0);
```

If the above functions are run it will return the error.

I able to get a single value from the whole table set where value is less than one. But the ListDate for that value is  2015-03-14 so it should not be included because it is not coverted by the date range passed in the stored procedure.

So it seems that the stored procedure executes the function in the whole set first before joining and filtering the dataset with date range.

Is this expected?

Comment: could you please provide some sample data and the table structure of dbo.SampleList?

Comment: [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) In T-SQL, `BETWEEN` is an **inclusive** range. Rewrite your query with simple comparisons, like `<` or `<=`, especially when `datetime` type is involved. See also: [mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there's a guaranteed point where function gets executed, so my answer is it depends, it depends on query plan, on how "early" the optimizer decides to execute the function - before or after the join. To make sure the function is only executed for valid values, you can change to:

```
CASE WHEN sl.Value < 1 THEN 0 ELSE LOG10(sl.Value) END
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there could be a data issue here as the basic logic of your code doesn't cause an issue, see the below sample:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp1 ( id INT, val INT )
CREATE TABLE #temp2 ( id INT, val INT )

INSERT  INTO #temp1 ( id, val )
VALUES  ( 1, 1 ), ( 2, 10 ), ( 3, -1 ) -- Negative value for id=3 exculded in subquery

INSERT  INTO #temp2 ( id, val )
VALUES  ( 1, 1 ), ( 2, 10 ), ( 3, 20 ) 

SELECT  t1.id ,
        LOG10(t1.val) AS Val
FROM    #temp1 t1
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT * ,
                            RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY val ) ranked
                     FROM   #temp2
                     WHERE  id BETWEEN 1 AND 2  -- excludes id 3
                   ) t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
                           AND t2.ranked = 1

DROP TABLE #temp1
DROP TABLE #temp2
```

**Produces:**

```
id  val
1   0
2   1
```

If you modify the `BETWEEN` clause to `WHERE  id BETWEEN 1 AND 3`, you do see the error as the negative value is included.

So I'd triple check the data and if there's still an issue, try to post a small sample that recreates the issue.